# Two models in a single view without using a VM-class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to put two partialviews together but I keep getting errors.
I've got a Subject-model and a Category-model, and I've made partial views which seem to work perfectly, but when I put them together in a single view this pops up:

```
Error   1   'Myproject.Models.Subject' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
```

this is the only code in my view:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CategoryPartial", Myproject.Models.Category);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SubjectPartial", Myproject.Models.Subject);}
```

I guess I will have to create a seperate viewmodel if all else fails, but I thought on checking on here first

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing in the type of Model rather than an object.

```
void HtmlHelper.RenderPartial(string partialViewName, object model)
```

You could do this if you changed your code to;

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CategoryPartial", new Myproject.Models.Category());}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SubjectPartial", new Myproject.Models.Subject());}
```

Then you would need to populate the properties within each object.

An alternative is to change your code to call a class which returns the populated objects, e.g.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CategoryPartial", Myproject.Models.CategoryRepository.GetCategory(id));}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SubjectPartial", Myproject.Models.SubjectRepository.Get(id));}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be passing **instances** of those models to the partials, whereas you are just specifying the **types**, hence the error.

So yes, for this view, I would create a view model, something like:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public Category Category {get;set;}
    public Subject Subject {get;set;}
}
```

and then do:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CategoryPartial", Model.Category);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SubjectPartial", Model.Subject);}
```